# How the communication between different Namenodes is managed?

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2

Suppose, I have a federated cluster with two namenodes. Now at the same time both namenodes needs to write a file in hdfs. How is it ensured that both namenodes do not pick same block to write two different files?

Answer (score 0):

Those blocks would belong to different block pools (would be stored in two different dirs on a datanode)

Comment: Is it like, when the cluster is set up, all the blocks in the cluster are equally divided between namenodes?

Comment: Not necessarily. Each federated namenode would "represent" an independent distributed filesystem. A datanode would store blocks for each  namenode in a separate directoriy. So, even if block names would collide, the directories, where they are stored, will differ. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/Federation.html,  https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/ViewFs.html